# Way to modify Contact's ringtone via ABPerson class iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook, abperson

So I've been toying around with the AddressBook framework on iOS and have noticed in the ABPerson class, pretty much every attribute of a contact is listed as a constant (ref: [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)). However, one attribute I notice is missing is the ability to make a custom ringtone. Is there any way to modify the ringtone of a contact via the ABPerson class? If not, is there any way at all to modify the custom ringtone using the AddressBook framework? iOS 5.1.1.

Comment: Please don't. Why do you want to do this? What makes you think anyone would use your app if it did this?

Comment: My app does not just change ringtones. It is one component of it. Since you so adamantly do not think I should try to change custom ringtones, why not tell me how it's done and why I should not do it? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't mind a third-party app that does some things with ringtones that Apple doesn't, like assigning tones per group instead of per person. But I suspect the reason I've never seen such an app is because it's not possible. (And I suspect the reason for that is what @JonathanGrynspan is warning about... if there were an API for changing ringtones, apps could change 'em out from under you in unpleasant ways.)

Comment: GRingtones is an app that is able to do it. No one knows how it does it. This was a highly requested feature on our app, Groups, http://groups.qbix.com but no one seems to have any idea what APIs they used. They are in the store now!